# Python regex not detecting just numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to detect if a string is a Hex Code (please let me know if there is any better way to do it), but to begin with I started to check if the string I'm looking at is a number 0-9 of length 2:

```
def is_hex(text):
    if re.match('^[0-9]{0,2}',text):
        print("The text \n" + text + "\n has been identified as HEX code")
        print(re.search('^[0-9]{0,2}',text))
    else:
        print("The text \n" + text + "\n has >NOT< been identified as HEX code")
```

Then I run some tests, but ANY string will go through, just like this one "Proba de Merda":

The text
Proba de Merda
 has been identified as HEX code

Evaluate next item

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: `'^[0-9]{0,2}'` matches an empty string. You need `'^[0-9]{1,2}'` to match 1 or 2 digits at the start or just `[0-9]+` (with `re.match`, it will require one or more digits at the start of the string)

Comment: @alejandro-a check this topic >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592261/check-if-a-string-is-hexadecimal

it gives 2 alternatives for checking if the string is a hex string. in your code you forget to check the alphabetic characters [a-f]